# My variable that I created, is not working inside another function

Tags: python, parameters

I am dealing with a NameError at the moment. I have created multiple functions (for a project that I am working on). A variable that I've created, has to be used in multiple functions. I gave this variable as a parameter in all of the other functions and I had no problem at all. A friend of mine has written the menu function, which I have to connect with the functions I have created. I try to give "antwoorden_list" (which is created inside the function 'vragenLijst') as a parameter, because i need to use this variable inside the "menu" function.. Unfortunately I get this error message;

```
  File "/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/IPOHBO/sorteerhoed/sorteerhoed menu.py", line 276, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/IPOHBO/sorteerhoed/sorteerhoed menu.py", line 271, in main
    menu(antwoorden_list)
NameError: name 'antwoorden_list' is not defined
```

I have no idea why this message is popping, because I have defined antwoorden_list as a parameter.

This is the part of my code which is not working;

```
##MAIN MENU
def menu(antwoorden_list):
    color.write("\n" + "Welkom bij het ICT Sorteerhoed menu   " ,"DEFINITION")
    color.write(naam  + "\n","KEYWORD")
    infoApplicatie()
    sleep(0.5)
    print("_____________________________________\n")
    print("1. Quiz beginnen")
    print("2. Specialisaties bekijken")
    print("3. Resultaten bekijken")
    print("4. Programma sluiten")       
    print("_____________________________________\n")
    sleep(0.9)
    menuchoice = input("selecteer optie:  ")

##SELECTION
    if menuchoice == "1":
        quiz(antwoorden_list)
    elif menuchoice == "2":
        specialisatiemenu()
    elif menuchoice == "3":
        resultatenmenu(antwoorden_list)
    elif menuchoice == "4":
        exit()

def vragenLijst(antwoorden_list):
    print("De vragen worden geladen... ")
    sleep(2.0)
    print()
    print("Goed om te weten: de vragen kunnen alleen beantwoord worden met 'ja' en 'nee', zolang je dit niet invoert, zullen de vragen verder gesteld worden.")
    sleep(3.0)
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")



    vragen_list = open("vragenspecialisaties.txt").readlines()
    vragen_list_index = list(enumerate(vragen_list, 1))
    vragen_list_dict = dict(vragen_list_index) 


    antwoorden_list = [] 
    while vragen_list_dict:
        key = choice(list(vragen_list_dict)) 
        antwoord = input(vragen_list_dict[key] + "(ja/nee): ") 
        if antwoord == "ja" or antwoord == "nee":
            antwoorden_list.append((key, antwoord)) 
            antwoorden_list.sort() 
            del vragen_list_dict[key] 
            return antwoorden_list
        
        antwoorden_user = open("antwoorden_user.txt", "a")
        antwoorden_user.write(naam + ": " + str(antwoorden_list) + "\n")
        antwoorden_user.close()

def main():
    menu(antwoorden_list)
    infoApplicatie()
    variabelen(antwoorden_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I will appreciate all the help!

Comment: _I have no idea why this message is popping, because I have defined antwoorden_list as a parameter._ What behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: you need to call `vragenLijst()` and return `antwoorden_list` and then call `menu(antwoorden_list)`

Comment: I want that the menu function runs first. After that, I want that the user decides what he does(with his input)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script, the `main()` function runs at first. So do the variable declarations inside `main()` before calling the functions.

Comment: What do you exactly mean

Comment: Where do you declare antwoorden_list?

Comment: Well when I was writing my own functions for this project, I used antwoorden_list in all the functions parameters. And this worked really fine for me..

Comment: I tried to declare it in main like ; antwoorden_list = vragenLijst() , but then it starts running all the questions from the function vragenLijst()